# Drop and expire all cookies with a specific prefix

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, cookie, woocommerce

We're running a WordPress site with WooCommerce. A third party plugin was injecting (`sbjs_*`) cookies into our site to track purchases and provide us with additional reporting. Unfortunately, something's gone wrong with the plugin and all web requests with `sbjs` cookies set result in a 403.

To fix this issue I've disabled the plugin, however, the `sbjs` cookies have an expiry of 6 months, which means all visitors who've visited us before, have cached the cookies, and get the 403 error.

1. How do I remove the bad cookies from all requests, but leave the cookies needed for WooCommerce and our payment gateways, etc.

   I've tried `.htaccess`:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} sbjs_migrations|sbjs_current_add|sbjs_first_add|sbjs_first|sbjs_current|sbjs_udata
   RequestHeader unset Cookie
   ```

   However, this of course kills all cookies, which I don't really want to do as it breaks other functionality.
2. How do I expire those cookies, so that anyone visiting the site who has the cookies, will have them erased before their expiry date? (ie something in the page header?)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} sbjs_migrations|sbjs_current_add|sbjs_first_add|sbjs_first|sbjs_current|sbjs_udata
> RequestHeader unset Cookie
> ```

Note that `RewriteCond` (mod_rewrite) and `RequestHeader` (mod_headers) are unrelated.

You need to modify/edit the `Cookie` HTTP request header to remove just those specific cookies, which you can do using the `RequestHeader` directive with the `edit` parameter to perform a "search and replace". For example:

```
RequestHeader edit* Cookie "\bsbjs_[a-z_]+=[^;]+(; )?" ""
```

The above applies the regex `\bsbjs_[a-z_]+=[^;]+(; )?` to the `Cookie` header (ie. to match cookies that start `sbjs_`) and replaces all instances with `""` (ie. an empty string), essentially erasing that cookie from the `Cookie` header. The `*` in `edit*` ensures that all instances are replaced, not just the first one.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader

Note that this doesn't strictly "expire" the cookies on the client (although that is how it appears to the application). The cookies set on the client machine are unchanged and sent with every request and so will still be left to expire in 6 months time (or whenever). The above directive simply prevents these cookies from reaching your application.

To actually *expire* these cookies on the client you would need to send back a `Set-Cookie` header with an expiry date in the past (which you could do from either WordPress/PHP or `.htaccess` - but note that WP would override `.htaccess` in this instance). However, you would also need to set/expire the cookie using the same URL-path and domain as used when the original cookie was set, otherwise, this will have no effect.

However, it does seem a bit odd that even after disabling the plugin, the very presence of these cookies triggers a 403 - there would seem to be *another* plugin (or *something*) that is doing that?